# Reticulate error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, r, list, numpy, reticulate

I am trying to run a Python function `fitKCA` within the R environment through the package `reticulate`.

The function is sourced correctly and all I do is to call the function:

`fitKCA(z = bh$V1, q = 0.1)`

and pass the two arguments:

- `bh$V1`, a column (of type `dbl`) of a tibble
- `q`, a scalar

Nevertheless, I get the following error message:

`Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords):AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`

In my understanding, the column of the tibble extracted through the `$` sign is of the R type `list` and this clashes with the Python `numpy` library and hence has no `shape` attribute.

So my questions are:

1. how can I avoid this error?
2. How do R objects match Python objects (i.e. if I use the `$` sign is it compatible with `numpy` or `pandas`? Or what if I use instead `bh[,2]` or `bh[,"V1"]`, is there any difference?)?

Many thanks and forgive my evident lack of computer science background.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try this:

```
fitKCA(z = as.matrix(bh$V1), q = 0.1)
```